# Evitar Sesion En 2 Navegadores PHP

Tags: php, html

Buen Dia, quisiera saber si alguien sabe como evitar que un usuario entre en su sesion en un navegador distinto, el codigo que tengo es el siguiente si alguien sabe como se los agradecería demasiado

```html
<?php
//incluye la conexion

session_start();


require("Funciones/Conexion.php");
$mysqli=inicio();

//AQUI SE HACE LA VALIDACIÓN PARA EL ADMINISTRADOR PREDETERMINADO

$username=$_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena=$_POST['contrasena'];

$sql2=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$username'"); // Aquí hace la seleccion de la tabla usuarios de la base de datos

if($f2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)){
 if($contrasena==$f2['pasadmin']){ 
  $_SESSION['pasadmin']=$f2['pasadmin'];
  $_SESSION['idusuario']=$f2['idusuario'];
  $_SESSION['nombre']=$f2['nombre'];
  $_SESSION['login']=$f2['login'];
  
    //Aquí valida los campos de la tabla usuarios para Administrador

  print "<script>window.location='Administrador.php';</script>"; 
}
  }

$sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$username' and habilitado='1'");
 if($f=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  if($comprobar_pass=password_verify($contrasena,$f['contrasena'])){
   $_SESSION['idusuario']=$f['idusuario'];
   $_SESSION['nombre']=$f['nombre'];
   $_SESSION['activo']=$f['activo'];
   $_SESSION['correo']=$f['correo'];
   $_SESSION['login']=$f2['login'];

   header("Location: Usuario.php");
  }
  
if ($login == 1){
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "12056", "reloj");  
 $sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE usuarios SET login='1' WHERE correo='$username'");
else{
echo "Esta Cuenta Ha Sido Abierta En Otro Navegador";
}


  if(!isset($_SESSION['intentos'])) {
$intentos = 1; 

$_SESSION['intentos'] = $intentos;
} else {
$intentos = $_SESSION['intentos'];

}

$_SESSION["intentos"]++;
if ($_SESSION['intentos'] > 4)
{
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "12056", "reloj");  
 $sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE usuarios set habilitado='0' WHERE correo='$username'");


 echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
title:"Error",text:"Tu sesión a sido bloqueada, restablece tu contraseña presiona Aceptar",type:"error",confirmButtonText:"Aceptar"
},function(){location.href="pass/nueva.php";});});</script>';

 session_destroy(); 
}else{ 
echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
title:"Error",text:"Contraseña Incorrecta, Llevas ('.($_SESSION['intentos']-1).') Intento de 3 Intentos ",type:"warning",confirmButtonText:"Aceptar"
},function(){location.href="Index.php";});});</script>';
}

 }else{

  echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
title:"Error",text:"Esta Cuenta A Sido Bloqueada",type:"error",confirmButtonText:"Aceptar"
},function(){location.href="Index.php";});});</script>';
 }






?>
```

Answer (score 1):

En un proyecto tuve la misma situación, y la solución que se realizó fue la de registrar en BD que el usuario habia iniciado sesión. Al ingresar se realiza la validación correspondiente de que no tenga una sesión iniciada.

@Muriano, lo que comento es algo conceptal y por lo que veo en el código ya se esta implementando

```
if ($login == 1){
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "12056", "reloj");      
  $sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE usuarios SET login='1' WHERE correo='$username'");
else{
  echo "Esta Cuenta Ha Sido Abierta En Otro Navegador";}
```

Sin embargo no entiendo por que se valida que el campo loguin sea igual a 1 (`if ($login == 1)`) y si es verdad, este campo se vuelve a setear a 1 (`...UPDATE usuarios SET login=1 ...`), al parecer esto es lo que hace que el usuario se pueda autenticar en varios navegadores. el if se deberia reemplazar por

```
if ($login == _condicion_de_no_estar_logueado_){...}else{...}
```

Y cuando el usuario cierre la sesión devolver al estado de _no_logueado_

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE usuarios SET login='_condicion_de_no_estar_logueado_' WHERE correo='$username'");
```

Comment: Podrías añadir algo de contexto a tu respuesta? Quizás código de ejemplo o pseudocódigo que sirva al usuario como guía para solucionar su problema?